# How to url rewrite in dynamic subdomains link test.domain.com/anything

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working in php with htaccess.
I want Url rewrite like : http://usa.classifiedexpert.com/automobiles

Please help me how to get this type url in php with htaccess

My code is:

```
RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ])$ main.php?country=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) main.php?country=%1


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ country-category.php?country=$1&category=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, many details are left undefined, so we can only assume this is what you are looking for... You certainly will have to adapt it to your specific needs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /main.php?country=%1 [END]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ country-category.php?country=%1&category=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).